# make vim produce patch files without editing originals

Tags: vimdiff, swap-file

I want to edit text files with vim, I would love

```
vim file.txt
```

To work like normal, and open `file.txt` in vim, like normal, and allow me to edit it *seemingly* like normal.

The only difference is, all writes `:w` or anything, don't re-write file.txt, instead they write to some patch file that shows the differences between the original file and the edited one I am writing.

So after I have finished editing, i should have `file.txt` and `file.txt.diff`, and `file.txt` is identical to how it was before I started editing and `file.txt.diff`, if patched onto `file.txt`, would make `file.txt` look like it did after my edits.

The next time I run `vim file.txt` it would load the file with the patch, and I can continue editing from how it last "was".

Comment: Are you looking for version control? `git` simulates this with it’s index.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have a bunch of source code that I don't want to put on github, but I do want people to be able to see what changes I make to the original code

Comment: One can use git without using GitHub; local copies, your own server, &c. GitHub is just a convenient cloud solution (but does allow private repos). It does precisely what you ask.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I want the changes I make to the code to be publicly visible

Comment: Either I would write a script, that handle this stuff outside Vim. Or much better: I would use git locally and create diffs between versions to release. Anyway this is nothing that should be handled in Vim IMHO.

Comment: @Ralf I thought of using git but it's awkward because I need some version of the og file committed to be able to `git diff` it

Comment: I think I need two got repositories right? One which I actually code in, and the other just stores the patch files